# How to execute external application with arguments and receive result

Tags: java, processbuilder

How do i execute external application and pass the arguments and return the result from external application using java #ProcessBuilder and #RunTime ?

```
public class test {



public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Starting Application");
    //    Runtime runtime =Runtime.getRuntime();

        Process proc= new ProcessBuilder("NconnectLicenseGenerator.exe","ABCDEFGHIJK").start();
        InputStream is = proc.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line;
        System.out.printf("Output of the program is %s :" ,Arrays.toString(args));
```

Here I want to pass the Arguments to my App and submit the arguments through Java and return the results

```
        while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
        {
            System.out.println(line);
        }

        System.out.println("Closing Application");
    } catch (IOException e) {            
        e.printStackTrace();
    }      
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem by making a console application in .net and using it with java process-builder.

Answer (score 3):

You can find here how to send command-line arguments to your Java app:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html

As for calling the external program in Java:
    Process proc = new ProcessBuilder("NconnectLicenseGenerator.exe", String.join(" ", args).start();

Comment: Actually the application in which I'm passing the arguments is a .NET one, and i tried this , its still not working ,can you help me please?

Comment: @Pranay Chandale, please remove the java tag, add C#

Comment: Bro i need to control .NET application using Java

Comment: Please help me locate your problem. Is it when you are trying to get the stdout of NconnectLicenseGenerator.exe? Or is it because of an improper call to NconnectLicenseGenerator.exe? Do you have access to the source code of NconnectLicenseGenerator.exe?